# Tabledrag with locked children

Tags: javascript

We use Drupal's tabledrag component in one of our interfaces and we've got this requirement we don't know how to solve.

Basically, we have a tree structure with elements of 2 types - let's call them A and B.

An element of type A can be moved to any location in the tree (we use weight and parent-child relationships).
An element of type B **is always a child of an A, and cannot be moved to another A**. It is locked under it's parent A. However, **it can be sorted with sibling As**.

So for a tree like:

```
A1
\- A2
 - B1
 - A3
   \- B2
    - A4
    - B3
    - B4
```

We can move A3 up to be a child of A2, and all it's children (B2..B4) will move along (like normal).
However, **B1 can only be moved up and down** (in regards to A2 and A3), as we can change it's weight, but cannot change it's parent: **it's locked under A1**.

I have searched for a while, but have not found any examples of this. Is this even possible with Drupal's core tabledrag ?

Comment: As a starting point, all elements of type B need to have a class of "tabledrag-leaf". This will prevent them from having child items. But it does not prevent them from being dragged to other As.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, found it.

If one includes this code, it will prevent all items with a class "tabledrag-parent-locked" from being dragged into another group, while still being orderable with their siblings.

This code uses a CSS class of 'parent' to target the parent relation field. The actual CSS class would obviously depend on what CSS class you pass to `drupal_add_tabledrag()`.

```
/**
 * @file
 * Override some Tabledrag functionality.
 */

/**
 * If the dragged row has a class of 'tabledrag-parent-locked', check the rows with which it might get swapped.
 * If the row it gets swapped with has a different  parent, block the swap by returning false.
 * This will prevent the locked child from being dragged to another parent.
 *
 * @override Drupal.tableDrag.row.isValidSwap
 */
// Keep the original implementation - we still need it.
Drupal.tableDrag.prototype.row.prototype._isValidSwap = Drupal.tableDrag.prototype.row.prototype.isValidSwap;
Drupal.tableDrag.prototype.row.prototype.isValidSwap = function(row) {
  if (this.indentEnabled && $(this.element).hasClass('tabledrag-parent-locked')) {
    var nextRow;
    if (this.direction == 'down') {
      nextRow = $(row).next('tr').get(0);
    }
    else {
      nextRow = row;
    }

    if (nextRow && $('.parent', this.element).val() !== $('.parent', nextRow).val()) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  // Return the original result.
  return this._isValidSwap(row);
}

/**
 * If the dragged row has a class of 'tabledrag-parent-locked', disable the indentation for the duration of
 * the drag. Store the old indentation setting in _indentEnabled.
 *
 * @override Drupal.tableDrag.dragRow
 */
// Keep the original implementation - we still need it.
Drupal.tableDrag.prototype._dragRow = Drupal.tableDrag.prototype.dragRow;
Drupal.tableDrag.prototype.dragRow = function(event, self) {
  if (self.rowObject && $(self.rowObject.element).hasClass('tabledrag-parent-locked')) {
    if (self.indentEnabled) {
      self._indentEnabled = true;
      self.indentEnabled = false;
    }
  }

  return self._dragRow(event, self);
}

/**
 * Restore the original indentation setting, if needed.
 *
 * @override Drupal.tableDrag.dragRow
 */
// Keep the original implementation - we still need it.
Drupal.tableDrag.prototype._dropRow = Drupal.tableDrag.prototype.dropRow;
Drupal.tableDrag.prototype.dropRow = function(event, self) {
  if (self._indentEnabled !== null) {
    self.indentEnabled = true;
    self._indentEnabled = null;
  }

  return self._dropRow(event, self);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, used your approach [here](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/79665/in-tabledrag-form-how-to-prevent-certain-elements-from-having-children/80117#80117). Saved my day.