# In tabledrag form, how to prevent certain elements from having children?

Tags: forms, javascript, theming

I want to use tabledrag to manage 2 kinds of elements. Let's call them branches and leaves. Branch can be parent to both branches and leaves. Leaf cannot be parent to anything. A support for [class `tabledrag-parent-locked` preventing change of a parent](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/60758/tabledrag-with-locked-children) can be added, but that's not exactly what I want, I actually want to be able change parents, just to other designated parents.

So, is there any class or module to get that effect?

Comment: The `tabledrag-parent-locked` class is a completely custom thing based on the script in the question you linked to - core doesn't use that class at all (it's not even in the codebase). I expect you need to override the same functions as in the other post and tweak the logic to deny dropping, rather than denying indentation

Comment: @Clive thanks, fixed question. And I'm afraid you may be right. If I'll do it, I'll post a self answer.

Comment: My answer deleted as I found a bugs in it, that allowed it to fail sometimes.